# Angular Incremental Count inside setInterval

Tags: angular, typescript

i am starting with Ts and angular and i cant find what i am doing wrong.

I have a button in my template that start and end a counter, it logs the number and for some reason the counter stays at 0.

```
<body> 
      <button (click)="onStart()">Start Game</button>
      <button (click)="onEnd()">End Game</button> 
 </body>
```

```
number:number = 0;
interval:any;
```

```
onStart(){
 this.interval = setInterval(
   function() {this.number+=1;}
   ,1000);
   console.log(this.number);
   }
onEnd(){
 console.log(this.number);
 clearInterval(this.interval);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the scope, when you create anonymous function with `function` keyword a new scope is created and this would override the parent parent class `this`. So `number` would not be accessible with keyword `this` since it's not defined within function. To overcome this you can use `arrow function`:

```
  onStart() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.number += 1;
    }, 1000);
    console.log(this.number);
  }
```

Or you can copy the parents `this` into another variable and use that inside your function.

```
  onStart() {
    const scope = this;
    this.interval = setInterval(function () {
      scope.number += 1;
    }, 1000);
    console.log(this.number);
  }
```